Celery pytest fixtures with embedded delay calls
I have an example project for celery test fixtures
my directory structure:
src/celery_tasks.py
test/test_example.py
test/conftest.py

src/celery_tasks.py contains:
from celery import Celery

app = Celery("hello", broker="amqp://guest@localhost//")


@app.task
def hellothenmultiply(x, y):
    print("hello")
    return multiply.delay(x, y)


@app.task
def multiply(x, y):
    return x * y

test/conftest.py contains
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def celery_enable_logging():
    return True

and test/test_example.py contains:
import src.celery_tasks

def test_multiply(celery_session_worker):
    assert src.celery_tasks.multiply(4, 5) == 20


def test_hello_then_multiply(celery_session_worker):
    assert src.celery_tasks.hellothenmultiply(4, 5) == 20


The first test, test_multiply works! However, the second test test_hello_then_multiply does not. The reason is the embedded .delay call in the hellothenmultiply function. The celery test fixture does not recognize that it should run multiply.delay on the fixture celery worker when it is embedded inside of another celery task.
I thought adding the following block to conftest.py would fix the issue, but it does not.
@pytest.fixture
def celery_includes():
    return ["src.celery_tasks"]

How can I fix this?
